# Launching Web (Silverlight Application) in Debug mode getting Error

Tags: silverlight, web-config

I am getting an error when trying to debug into my Silverlight application. Does anybody know what might be wrong? I tried the Things you can try section to no avail.

[error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojYV9.png)

Comment: You haven't show nus the actual error you are getting, this is just a generic message saying that something has gone wrong. Are you running your silverlight app in IIS?

Comment: Do you have a start page set in Visual Studio? Or based on your error it appears you're using IIS, you probably need to set a "Default Document" to match your start page.